# Three.JS Environment MAP THREE.JSONLoader()

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi i need to load environment map from a jpg file ( env.jpg ) on to a object loaded using THREE.JSONLoader(), ( i was unable to export this map using maya  so it needs to be added like this ) how can i do this? my code is bellow.

Thank you

```
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'assets/alexander_test.json',

            // onLoad callback
            function ( geometry, materials ) {
                //new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
                var material = materials[ 0 ];
                console.log(material.normalMap);
                var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                object.castShadow = true;
                object.receiveShadow = true;
                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                           child.receiveShadow = true;
                           child.castShadow = true;
                    }
                });

                scene.add( object );
            },

            // onProgress callback
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
            },

            // onError callback
            function( err ) {
                console.log( 'An error happened' );
            }
        );
```

EDIT:

here is the online example: http://a3d.joladev2.com/webgl-env-map/index.html
here is the environment map: http://a3d.joladev2.com/webgl-env-map/assets/env.jpg

EDIT:

here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xk12n88z/4/

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use a JSONLoader to load an image file?

Comment: I am not using JSONLOader to load an image file, i am using it to load an object which is a Json file, i need to load environment map to this object which is a .jpg file, if you have a better way of adding an environment map please say so. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resolved,

So in my case ( and i do not know if this is correct ),

OBJ and MTL loader would not load normal map or environment map, so i had to switch to json loader which did load normal map but would not load environment map. Then i switched to FBX loader, that has loaded everything

here is working example: http://a3d.joladev2.com/evironment-map-done/index.html

here is the code i used:

```
            var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
            loader.load( 'assets/6507T_webgl_nolights.fbx', function ( object ) {

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child.isMesh ) {

                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.receiveShadow = true;

                    }

                } );

                scene.add( object );

            } );
```